# Logging in C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services

What is the best way to 'log' Windows Service activity, should I use Windows Log Event Viewer, or just use plain txt file. If I use event log, I think there is a chance of being the event log full.

Comment: I tend to log starting, stopping, ... and critical stuff in the EventLog and everything else with log4Net (Nuget).

Comment: Like @Romano, I find the Windows Event Log useful for critical activities. I log other events into a database from which a more user friendly interface can be provided. But if you can't connect to the database, I find the Windows Event log preferable to a text file. The only thing to be aware of is that admin rights are required to create the initial 'source'. I also log unexpected exceptions to the Windows event log.

Answer (score 2):

My new favourite logging framework is [Serilog](https://serilog.net/). We make use of [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack) for log aggregation and so Serilog is setup to write logs JSON format, e.g.

```
{"Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Service Started","Timestamp":"2017-07-27T11:29:54.3948669+01:00"}
{"Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Service Stopped","Timestamp":"2017-07-27T11:31:14.8305763+01:00"}
```

These logs are then sent for aggregation and are visible and searchable via a web interface - we don't bother logging to the event log because nobody logs onto these boxes.

If you only have a couple of services then log aggregation might be overkill - its easy enough to have Serilog write to other formats instead (e.g. to the event log, or non-json formatted files which are easier for humans to read).

Definitely use a logging framework ([log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) is also good, I've also heard good things about [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) but never used it myself). Any good logging framework will let you selectively log important messages to the event log.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the NLog library. 
[link](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/EventLog-target)
Then you are free to choose File or EventViewer depending on the customer expectations.

From the support people point of view I would use the event viewer because it is easy to reach. (but do not flood it with info messages, just error)

Comment: Yes. I can use event viewer for errors, but for information :(. If the event viewer is full what will happen, will the service fail or just the event writing will fail ?

Comment: you can define two different appenders: to txt file that collects all the log level, to event viewer that collects only errors.  So the users can connect to EventViewer to look at problems and then afterwards check in the logs for more information. I would create daily logs and compress them with a script every night.